# ¿Usar constante mágica __DIR__ es seguro?

Tags: php, seguridad

Estoy desarrollando un fichero que contenga una serie de rutas para acceder a determinados recursos del proyecto.

Para generar las rutas necesarias, utilizo `__DIR__` y juego con el dato que me arroja. En función de si me encuentro en local, pruebas o producción, genero unas rutas u otras y las defino en constantes.

En sí, lo tengo finalizado y funcionando adecuadamente en cada uno de los entornos, pero me plantea una duda, llevar a cabo ésta práctica puede resultar un agujero de seguridad?

Es decir, ¿definir en constantes rutas a partir de lo obtenido de `__DIR__` y no definirlas, vamos a decir, "a mano", puede resultar peligroso o sería correcto?

Comment: Para nada, `__DIR__` existe precisamente por eso y para eso y haces bien en usarlo. La seguridad no queda comprometida por su uso.

Comment: un indicio si es inseguro las funciones, métodos y constante es verificar primero si es obsoleto, y no lo es, en cuanto a seguridad la persona que tiene acceso ver el `__DIR__ ` en el código también puede ver los archivos de configuración de base de datos; por lo tanto es un sysAdmin o un Hacker , en conclusion es seguro pero debes preocuparte de levantar bien las politicas de  seguridad de tu servidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente el uso de **__DIR__** no tiene ningun problema de seguridad y es ampliamente utilizado en los sistemas más empleados para la carga de ficheros y clases, por ejemplo en ***[Composer](https://getcomposer.org)*** que ahora mismo se usa sino en todos en la mayoría de *frameworks PHP* con este fin. Yo personalmente también la utilizo en combinación con **dirname()**.

Te dejo un extracto del fichero "autoload_files.php" de *Composer*:

```
// autoload_files.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);
```

Aquí se usa la función dirname en su forma compatible con PHP 4 y 5, con PHP7 adoptaría esta otra:

```
$vendorDir = (dirname(__FILE__, 2);
```

Documentación de la función [dirname](http://php.net/manual/es/function.dirname.php).